# Newton- Euler Rigid Body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics

Hello i am busy using Newton-Euler equations to get the dynamic of a quad drone. 
However, as I am looking online at papers I see mostly 2 different kinds of equations.

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
mI & 0 \\
0 & J
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{v}_G \\
\dot{\omega}_G
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
m\omega_G\times v_G \\
\omega_G\times J\omega_G
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f \\
\tau_G
\end{bmatrix}
\tag1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
mI & 0 \\
0 & J
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{v}_G \\
\dot{\omega}_G
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
\omega_G\times J\omega_G
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f \\
\tau_G
\end{bmatrix}
\tag2
\end{equation}

Even equation 2 is found on wikipedia but most papers use equation 1 and my question is, what is the difference and when are both of them used??

Comment: Don't the online papers/wikipedia tell you how to use these equations?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could link to some of the papers that you have been reading.

Comment: It depends if $\dot{v}_G$ is material or spatial acceleration.

Comment: Related [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298125/understanding-terms-twist-and-wrench/298159#298159)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper equation at the center of mass is

$$\begin{aligned} 
\hat{f}_G &= \hat{\rm J}_G\, \dot{\hat{v}_G} + \hat{v}_G \times \hat{\rm J}_G\,\hat{v}_G \\
 \begin{bmatrix}f\\
\tau_{G}
\end{bmatrix} & =\begin{bmatrix}m\\
 & J
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot{v}_{G}\\
\dot{\omega}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\omega\times & 0\\
v_{G}\times & \omega\times
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}m\\
 & J
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_{G}\\
\omega
\end{bmatrix} \\
 & = \begin{bmatrix}m\\
 & J
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot{v}_{G}\\
\dot{\omega}
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\omega\times m\,v_{G}\\
\omega\times J\omega
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned} $$

where $v_G$ is the velocity at the center of mass, and $\dot{v}_G$ is the [spatial acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_acceleration) at the center of mass.

The material acceleration of the center of mass is

$$ a_G = \dot{v}_G + \omega \times v_G $$ as well as the identity $$\alpha = \dot{\omega} $$

**Proof**

The standard form of the equations is

$$ \begin{aligned}
 f & = m a_G \\
 \tau_G & = J \alpha + \omega \times J \omega
\end{aligned}$$

and $$ f  = m (\dot{v}_G + \omega \times v_G) = m \dot{v}_G + \omega \times (m v_G) $$

---

At some other location *A*, other than the center of mass, where $c$ is vector from that location to the CM the NE equations of motion are

$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{f}_A &= \hat{\rm J}_A\, \dot{\hat{v}_A} + \hat{v}_A \times \hat{\rm J}_A\,\hat{v}_A \\
 \begin{bmatrix}f\\
\tau_{A}
\end{bmatrix}  & =\begin{bmatrix}m & -m [c \times] \\ m [c \times]
 & J-m [c\times][c\times]
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot{v}_{A}\\
\dot{\omega}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\omega\times & 0\\
v_{A}\times & \omega\times
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}m & -m [c \times] \\ m [c \times]
 & J-m [c\times][c\times]
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_{A}\\
\omega
\end{bmatrix} \end{aligned} $$

I leave it up to the reader the prove this, based on the standard transformation equations for torque, velocity and spatial acceleration.

Please [read this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/298159/392) for the geometric foundation of the above equations

Comment: I edited the answer with more details.