# Is Conservation of Linear Momentum subservient to conservation of Angular Momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws

When particles physically interact, they transfer linear momentum and angular momentum between one another via force .

When particle P1 exerts force on particle P2, P2 exerts an equal and vectorially opposite force on P1 . That way, any momentum leaving P1 is attached to P2, and total momentum is conserved.

"equal and opposite force" is a necessary and sufficient condition for conservation of linear momentum.

But linear momentum is uncaring about the direction of the force, so long as it is equal and opposite.

If P1 and P2 were on opposite sides of a chosen origin point, at x,y (1,0) and (-1, 0) , and P1 put a +Y ( clockwise ) force on P2, the vectorially opposite -Y force on P1 on the other side of the origin point would also be clockwise around the origin.
That would perfectly satisfy "equal and opposite", and therefore satisfy conservation of linear momentum, but would violate conservation of angular momentum. Particles in our universe cannot do this.

Equal and opposite forces along a single straight line do not create torque or modify total angular momentum when viewed from any arbitrary origin point .

"Equal and Opposite force, along the path of separation" ( attraction or repulsion only ) is a necessary and sufficient condition for conservation of Angular Momentum to all origin points .
( It is possible to choose origin points to ignore various torques . But true conservation of Angular Momentum works from any and all origins )

So, from this point of view, it appears as if the more stringent "Equal and Opposite force, along the path of separation" of Angular Momentum automatically enforces the less stringent
"Equal and Opposite force" of linear momentum .

So, is conservation of linear momentum a simplified consequence of conservation of Angular momentum ?

Here is a messy supporting argument :

If a finite number of particles were interacting in a finite sized cube ( perhaps 1 meter across ), and you chose an origin point at z = 1 million meters, and you measured the
angular momentum around your chosen origin, you could get a pretty accurate estimate of the total linear (x,y) momentum of those particles by dividing the measured angular momentum by the
vector to the center of the box. You could make your estimate arbitrarily accurate by increasing your distance.

Conservation of angular momentum from this far origin point would imply that linear momentum was arbitrarily close to being conserved.

I have never seen thes arguments stated anywhere in print or elsewhere.

As an undergraduate circa 1981, I briefly showed this argument to my favorite physics professor, who off-the-cuff said he thought that this was a known fact. I was confused as to why it was not covered in the Halliday and Resnick.

So, is this a correct or incorrect concept ?

Can anyone find a hole in my not-terribly-complicated math ?

Does it appear in current textbooks ?

Comment: Newton's Third law considers the fact that you pointed out, that is it states that force on one object equals the one on another via the line joining them. As for the linear momentum being derived from angular momentum, I suggest you check out:  An Introduction to Mechanics 2nd Edition by Kleppner and Kolenkow's Chapter 8 and Introduction to Classical Mechanics By Morin's Chapter 9

Comment: The short answer to the title of your post is No. The laws of conservation of linear and angular momentum are independent of one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only does conservation of Angular Momentum $\vec{L}$ imply and enforce conservation of Linear Momentum $\vec{p}$, but you can calculate the value of $\vec{p}$ from $\vec{L}$ :

$$  
 \vec{p} =  
   ( ( \frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial z} \times \vec{i} ) \times -\vec{j} )  
 + ( ( \frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial x} \times \vec{j} ) \times -\vec{k} )  
 + ( ( \frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial y} \times \vec{k} ) \times -\vec{i} )  
$$

Proof:

Given N bodies with positions $\vec{r1} .. \vec{rN} ,$

at any instant of time, Angular Momentum around ( variable origin point ) $\vec{G} : $

$ \vec{L}(\vec{G}) $$ = \sum (\vec{r}_i - \vec{G}) \times \vec{p}_i $

( consider the partial derivative varying $\vec{G}$ by $\partial z ) $

$ \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial z} = \sum (\frac {\partial \vec{r_i}}{\partial z} -  \frac {\partial \vec{G}}{\partial z } ) \times \vec{p}_i$

( $\vec{r_i}, \vec{p_i} $ are each constant with respect to variable $\vec{G}$ )

$ \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial z}  = - \sum ( \frac {\partial \vec{G}}{\partial z } ) \times \vec{p}_i  
$

( $\frac {\partial \vec{G}}{\partial z } = [0,0,1]$ )

$ \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial z}  = - \sum [0,0,1] \times \vec{p}_i $

$ \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial z}  = - \sum [- {p}_{iy}, p_{ix}, 0] $

$ \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial z}  = \sum [{p}_{iy}, - p_{ix}, 0] $

$ \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial z}  =  [{p}_{y}, - p_{x}, 0]$

( concentrate on $p_x$ )

$ \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial z} \times \vec{i} = [ {p}_{y} , -p_{x} , 0 ] \times \vec{i} = [0, 0, p_x]$

$ ( \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial z} \times \vec{i} ) \times (-\vec{j}) = [0, 0, p_x] \times (-\vec{j}) = [p_x, 0, 0 ] $

( I spare you the separate derivation of $p_y, p_z ) :$

$ ( \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial x} \times \vec{j} ) \times (-\vec{k}) = [0, p_{y}, 0]$

$ ( \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial y} \times \vec{k} ) \times (-\vec{i}) = [0, 0, p_{z}]$

$ \vec{p_{total}} =  
  ( ( \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial z} \times \vec{i} ) \times -\vec{j} )  
+ ( ( \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial x} \times \vec{j} ) \times -\vec{k} )  
+ ( ( \frac {\partial \vec{L}(\vec{G})}{\partial y} \times \vec{k} ) \times -\vec{i} )  
$

Proven .

$--$

Also, this leads to the equation ( which I numerically verified) : $$\vec{L}(\vec{r}) = \vec{L}(0,0,0) - \vec{r} \times \vec{p}$$

$--$

For a demonstration, I generated random numbers in Excel for 3 bodies :
B1 : 87 kg,  $\vec{r1} = [ 56, 72, 41] m ,\; \vec{v1} = [-13,-69,  2] m/s $
B2 : 24 kg,  $\vec{r2} = [-85,-99, 76] m ,\; \vec{v2} = [ 46, 80,-93] m/s $
B3 : 75 kg,  $\vec{r3} = [ 43,-23, 78] m ,\; \vec{v3} = [-22, 37,-26] m/s $

$ \vec{p1} = [-1131,-3864,  144] kg m/s $
$ \vec{p2} = [ 1104,-6800, 9207] kg m/s $
$ \vec{p3} = [-1650, 1591,  598] kg m/s $

$\vec{p}_{total} = [-1677,-9073,9949] kg m/s $

$L(0,0,0) = [-363753, 657650, 582807]$
$L(1,0,0) = [-363753, 667599, 591880]$
$L(0,1,0) = [-373702, 657650, 581130]$
$L(0,0,1) = [-372826, 659327, 582807]$
kg $m^2$ / s

( partial derivative is constant )

$\frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial x} = L(1,0,0) - L(0,0,0) = [    0, 9949, 9073]$
$\frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial y} = L(0,1,0) - L(0,0,0) = [-9949,    0,-1677]$
$\frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial z} = L(0,0,1) - L(0,0,0) = [-9073, 1677,    0]$
kg m / s

$\frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial x} \times \vec{j} = [-9073,    0,     0]$
$\frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial y} \times \vec{k} = [    0, 9949,     0]$
$\frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial z} \times \vec{i} = [    0,    0, -1677]$

$( \frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial x} \times \vec{j} ) \times -\vec{k} = [    0, -9073,    0]$
$( \frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial y} \times \vec{k} ) \times -\vec{i} = [    0,     0, 9949]$
$( \frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial z} \times \vec{i} ) \times -\vec{j} = [-1677,     0,    0]$

$  (( \frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial x} \times \vec{j} ) \times -\vec{k}) + (( \frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial y} \times \vec{k} ) \times -\vec{i}) + (( \frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial z} \times \vec{i} ) \times -\vec{j})$
$ = [-1677, -9073, 9949]$
$ = \vec{p} $
( Same numeric answer as above - so it works )

So Linear Momentum is made of the ( re-ordered ) ( constant ) partial derivatives of Conserved Angular Momentum !

Please check my work, find any errors, and do the stackExchange "is this useful or interesting ? "  thing .

Comment: Interesting. It is a cyclic relation if I got it correctly: $\frac{\partial L_i}{\partial X_j} = \epsilon_{ijk}p_k$. It remembers the derivatives of the Hamiltonian, also a conserved quantity, that returns $p$ or $\dot p$

Answer (score 9):

Conservation of linear and angular momentum arise from fundamental symmetries of spacetime via [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). Conservation of linear momentum comes from translational symmetry and conservation of angular momentum come from rotational symmetry. The two symmetries are not necessarily related so the two conservation laws are not necessarily related.

Your argument is based upon the notion that if we consider the entire system then both types of momentum are conserved, which is equivalent to saying that no external forces or torques are acting. But this is simply the statement that spacetime, i.e. the background on which the bodies move, obeys both symmetries. This is certainly true of flat spacetime but not necessarily true of curved spacetimes i.e. not necessarily true of the universe as a whole, though I concede that it does appear to be true for at least the bit of the universe we can see.

But in practice we are often considering systems in which we have a background field, for example motion in a $1/r$ potential ($1/r^2$ force) such as the gravitational field of a spherical mass. You would argue that this is not an inertial frame since we are taking the spherical mass to be fixed, and this is certainly true. However it is still the case that the symmetries of the system determine the conservation laws i.e. in this case the rotational symmetry means angular momentum is conserved while the lack of translational symmetry means linear momentum is not conserved. To argue that the two conservation laws are equivalent would be to ignore a property of the system that is very important for performing calculations.

Comment: Illuminating. I will need to learn how Noether's theorem applies to my question, which will take more than a week. Thanks.

Comment: Does 1/r have any bearing here ? 1/r does not effectively conserve angular Or linear. Consider AM around any point on the particles curved path. At the moment the particle passes through the point, its angular momentum is zero, but at any other time, it is non-zero. This system does not generally conserve Angular Momentum, does not obey "equal, opposite, along the line of separation", and we should not expect it to obey linear either.

Comment: @DavidGraham **Every** spherically symmetric potential potential conserves angular momentum, whether it's $1/r$, $1/r^2$, $e^{-r}$ or whatever other weird function of $r$ you can come up with. The conservation of angular momentum comes from the symmetry not from the details of the force.

Comment: Yes, 1/r potential 'conserves' AM around r=0 . And I take your point about Noether . But 1/r potential violates consv_AM measured from almost any other origin .  
Example : 1/r potential applies [0,2,0] N force on particle at (0,-7,0) . No torque around origin (0,0,0) . Ok .  
Torque around alternate origin (-3,-7, 0) is  r X F = [3,0,0] X [0,2,0] = [0,0,6] ( nonZero, violation ) .  
I asserted that FULL consv of AM ( every origin ) implies consv of LM ( which has no origin ). I currently assert nothing about consv_AM that only works around one point .

Comment: The potential is not spherically symmetric about any point not on the origin.

Comment: Yes, 1/r is only spherically symmetrical around (0,0,0), and only conserves AM around (0,0,0), and does not conserve LM .  My original post did not assert anything about such a situation, so 1/r does not represent a counter-example to my assertion .  Although 1/r presents a generally useful illustration of Noether's theorem, and taught me something useful, it is a change-of-subject on your part, and has no direct bearing on whether my assertion is correct or incorrect . Yes ?

Comment: What I'm saying is this is an example of where the symmetry sets the conservation laws, and in this case the spherical symmetry about the origin means angular momentum is conserved about the origin, while the lack of translational symmetry means linear momentum is not conserved. This is an exceedingly important principle that we teach to all physics students, and it shows that the two forms of momenta are not the same.

Comment: You appear to be obsessed with the fact that both are conserved on the global scale, but this is simply because both symmetries apply at the global scale. It does not mean that conservation of one type of momentum implies conservation of the other.

Comment: I asserted "red cars go fast". You asserted "my blue car does not go fast". I said "what does that have to do with red cars?" You said "blue cars are kinda like red cars". I said "do you know any slow red cars?" You said "my blue car does not go fast"

Comment: @JohnRennie You may want to check my post. I think clarified exactly what both of you are trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

I want to build on John Rennie's answer, which invokes Nother's theorem, because it actually clarifies your idea beautifully. I will assume we are considering Euclidean space throughout the entire post.

Now rotational symmetry does not necessarily say anything about translational symmetry. To quote John Rennie here,

> The two symmetries are not necessarily related so the two conservation laws are not necessarily related.

John Rennie rightfully invokes an example involving a system consisting of a spherically symmetric potential. For concreteness, we may consider the Coulomb potential $V(r) = A/r$ where $r$ is the distance from the origin and $A$ is some nonzero constant. This system has rotational symmetry about any axis going through the origin, and yet it very obviously has no translational symmetry.

However, there is a specialized case where a relationship between the two symmetries does exist. The key realization is that every translation in Euclidean space can be written as a composition of rotations. Because of this somewhat surprising fact, it follows that *if we postulate rotational symmetry about every possible axis, then translational symmetry necessarily follows for free*. In this specialized circumstance, there is a relationship between the two symmetries as you seem to be pointing out.

Again, I have to stress that this relationship only occurs in a special case. This explains why people seem to be talking past each other, and it also explains why no one is contradicting one another if you think about this carefully enough.

---

Returning back to my claim that every translation is a composition of rotations, I will demonstrate a case in two dimensional Euclidean space. The generalization is straightforward.

Lastly, it is crucial to understand that I will be talking about [transformations in the active sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation).

Suppose we have a translation of the form $T:(x, y)\mapsto (x+a, y)$. To write this in terms of rotations, define $R_{1}:(x, y)\mapsto (-x+a/2, -y)$ and $R_{2}:(x', y')\mapsto (-x'+3a/2, -y')$. Here $R_{1}$ is a counterclockwise $180^{\circ}$ rotation about the point $(a/4, 0)$, and $R_{2}$ is a counterclockwise $180^{\circ}$ rotation about the point $(3a/4, 0)$. The result, as one can check, is that
$$ T = R_{2}\circ R_{1}. $$
We can even demonstrate this visually (again keep in mind these are active transformations acting on points).

[image]

To generalize, simply consider that any translation of the form $(x, y, z)\mapsto (x+a, y+b, z+c)$ is really just three translations $(x, y, z)\mapsto (x+a, y, z)\mapsto (x+a, y+b, z)\mapsto (x+a, y+b, z+c)$.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation.  I hope to learn enough ( I am working through some mechanics texts ) to fully verify and re-appreciate it. I can believe that Noether's theorem has important things to say about the relationship of Csvn-of-AM and Csvn-of-LM .

Comment: In my own reply, which I marked as the answer, using vectors, I proved the equation $\vec{L}(\vec{r_2})-\vec{L}(\vec{r_1})=(\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2})\times\vec{p_{total}}$ This equation is worth knowing, as it has significant implications.

Comment: This equation explains and expands on HGoldstein's "total AM = AM around center-of-mass + AM of center-of-mass". It relates LM directly to AM . It explains why, when LM=0, AM is equal from all origin points. It means that AM grows linearly across the vector field. It shows that, given AM at any three nonlinear points, you can calculate total LM, without even knowing the number of particles. It demands that, if AM is conserved at three non-linear points, then LM must also be conserved. Those are things worth knowing.

Comment: After searching a number of standard mechanics texts, I found that "A Course in Theoretical Physics volume 1 3ed : Mechanics", by Landau and Lifshitz, page 20, contains the main equation of my solution, so I cannot (and do not) claim originality. They derived and used it to translate Angular momentum between reference frames.

I find it hard to understand why this equation, which fundamentally links Angular and Linear Momentum, and solves many mechanics problems, is not featured in all mechanics texts.

Comment: @DavidGraham That's genuinely fascinating. I'll try to look into it myself as well. Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 1):

About linear momentum:
In order to have a definable linear momentum at all having a space with a single spatial degree of freedom to move along is already sufficient (obviously). Example: the physics demonstration that is known as an air rail.

About angular momentum:
In order to have a definable angular momentum the minimum is a space with two spatial degrees of freedom. The simplest case is two objects exerting a force upon each other, deflecting each other's motion. That motion is in a plane. (If the motion is in a space with three spatial degrees of freedom we can always transform to a coordinate system such that the plane of motion coincides with a plane of the coordinate system.) Demonstration is with an air table.

Here is a crucial property of any system with more than one spatial degree of freedom.

The motion of each of the participating objects can be decomposed in motion components, along the axes of the cartesian coordinate system that is used to describe the motion.

For example, the simple case of two objects of equal mass, attracting each other, circumnavigating the common center of mass in circular motion. Let the objects be named $0_1$ and $0_2$. For both $0_1$ and $0_2$ the motion can be decomposed in two perpendicular motion components. As we know, circular motion, when decomposed in two perpendicular motion components, results in two harmonic oscillations.

That is: if you project the two-dimensional circular motion onto a single degree of freedom the projected motion is harmonic oscillation. The projection of the force is according to Hooke's law. In all we have that each of the projected motions ($0_1$ and $0_2$ exerting a force upon each other, changing each other's momentum) satisfies conservation of linear momentum.

This generalizes to any form of interaction that acts from the center of mass of $0_1$ to the center of mass of $0_2$. Project the motions of the interacting objects onto two perpendicular axes. For each of the projections linear momentum is conserved

In that sense we can think of angular momentum as a combination of instances of linear momentum.

The connection between linear momentum and angular momentum can be represented in several different ways; this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian dynamics, "equal and opposite forces" has some technicalities to it that one should be aware of. The statement is that a force and its reaction are

1. equal in magnitude,
2. opposite in direction, and
3. lie on the same line.

For conservation of linear momentum, it's enough that (1) and (2) are true; (3) does not need to be true. But for conservation of angular momentum you need (3).

(As the other answer mentioned, in one dimension, (3) is not an issue because all vectors lie on the same line.)

For example, think of a particle at position $x_1=(0,1)$, and another particle at position $x_2=(0,-1)$. If you have a force $(1,0)$ on particle $1$ and $(-1,0)$ on particle 2, this would satisfy conditions (1) and (2), so it preserves linear momentum, but the forces are not on the same line, so (3) is violated and angular momentum is not conserved.

If you have conservation of angular momentum across all points in space, then yes, you have conservation of momentum too. This is particularly easy to see when you think of conserved quantities as generated by symmetries, you can get a translation (which corresponds to momentum symmetry), by rotating at opposite angles at two different points.

Answer (score 1):

As you very well explained, you need both when describing the laws of motion for rigid bodies.

1. "Equal and opposite force" on its own isn't sufficient because the location of the forces isn't specified. This just ensures the two bodies exchange an equal amount of momentum in terms of magnitude and direction. Let us specify the two forces $\vec{F}_1$ and $\vec{F}_2$ acting on the two bodies, and look at the change in total momentum of the system

   $$ \Delta \vec{p}  = \underbrace{ \int \vec{F}_1 \,{\rm d} t}_\text{body 1} + \underbrace{ \int \vec{F}_2 \,{\rm d} t}_\text{body 2} $$

   So what is the condition for **total momentum to be unchanged** $\Delta \vec{p}=0$?

   Since both bodies experience the same time in classical mechanics, the condition here is $\vec{F}_1 = -\vec{F}_2$ (equal and opposite forces, Newton's 2nd law).

   But what if the forces do not act through the same point?
2. "Equal and opposite force along the same line of action" is sufficient for most cases, except for some special cases. A line in space is specified by a direction (given by the force vector) and any point along the line (given by the point of contact $\vec{r}$)

   $$ \Delta \vec{L}  = \underbrace{ \int \vec{r}_1\times \vec{F}_1 \,{\rm d} t}_\text{body 1} + \underbrace{ \int \vec{r}_2\times\vec{F}_2 \,{\rm d} t}_\text{body 2} $$

   So what is the condition for **total angular momentum to be unchanged** $\Delta \vec{L} =0$?

   Here we need condition 1. from above, in addition to having a common point where the two forces act though. Actually, the condition is that each force acts through a point along a common line $(\vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 )\times \vec{F} = 0$. **This is called the line of action of the force** and it results in defining the line of action of momentum, commonly referred to as **axis of percussion**.

Your question is, do we need both, or 2. above is sufficient? My answer is yes we need both, because there are scenarios where $\vec{r}_1 \times \vec{F}_1 + \vec{r}_2 \times \vec{F}_2 =0$, but $\vec{F}_1 + \vec{F}_2 \neq 0$, which means angular momentum *is* conserved, but linear momentum *isn't*.

3. Now for a special case. Imagine an American football that flies through the air with some velocity $\vec{v}$ and at the same time a parallel spin $\vec{\omega}$ which results in linear momentum $\vec{p}$ and angular momentum $\vec{L}$ to be parallel to each other. This helical motion is the most general motion called a [screw twist](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298125/understanding-terms-twist-and-wrench/298159#298159).

   Can a single force/impulse stop all the motion of the football? Can a force along the axis of percussion produce the change in momentum and angular momentum to stop the ball?

   **The answer is no**. Conditions 1. and 2. above aren't totally sufficient here. A single force cannot provide the necessary momentum pair. You need a parallel torque in addition to the force to get

<sub>I removed the mathematical treatment of this condition for brevity.</sub>

Comment: If, around a particular reference origin, r1 cross F1 + r2 cross F2 = 0   but  F1 + F2 was non-zero, isn't that just cherry-picking a convenient refence origin ? Wouldn't choosing a different origin, with different r vectors, show that angular momentum was not really being conserved, just masked by the original origin point ?

Comment: @DavidGraham - I am not changing the point of summation (origin). For an arbitrary origin, there are cases where  $\vec{r}_1 \times \vec{F}_1 + \vec{r}_2 \times \vec{F}_2 =0
$ but $\vec{F}_1 + \vec{F}_2 \neq 0$. Think of two forces and the line connecting their points of application. If the perpendicular components of the forces balance out, but the parallel components do not. My point exactly is that conditions 1) and 2) are both required to solve most general cases without cherry picking the summation point.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the example where AM is conserved  ( around all origins ) but not LM . When AM is conserved, total torque is zero  .
 Using position of particle 1 as origin :  r1 = 0  ,  r1 X F1 = 0  ,  total = (r1 X F1) + (r2 X F2) = 0  ,  r2 X F2 = 0  ,  therefore F2 parallel to (r1-r2)  .
 Using position of particle 2 as origin : ... therefore F1 parallel to (r1-r2)  .
 Using a point 7 meters away from (r1-r2) as origin :  (7 X F1) + (7 X F2) = 0  ,  F1 + F2 = 0  .  LM conserved  .  Yes ?

Answer (score 1):

The two arguments you give in separate posts to prove the assertion in the OP, as well as the argument given in the OP, both rely on using the fact that the total angular momentum will be separately conserved around any reference point.

However, what you are doing here is assuming that the laws of physics don’t change with respect to different points in space.

It turns out, via Noether’s Theorem, that you don’t need to go this messy route of considering the total angular momentum at each point in space.

The assumption that the laws of physics are the same at every point in space (translational invariance) by itself is sufficient to show that total linear momentum is conserved.

In other words, your argument makes it seem like total linear momentum is conserved *because* the total angular momentum is conserved, but the actual crux of the issue is that the total linear momentum is conserved *because* you are assuming physics is the same about every “reference point.”

Of course, Noether’s Theorem is only about sufficient conditions. You could try to make the point that you are using weaker assumptions.

Comment: It also has to do with which conservation gives you more information. You cannot get and solve all the information about a system using Linear Momentum. Angular Momentum gives you everything Linear does, plus more.

Comment: The (answer) post where I derive $\vec{p}$ from $\frac {\partial \vec{L}}{\partial z}$ far supercedes my Original Post .
 It 'proves' a useful and apparently unknown relationship . It is either ( incorrect ) or ( old and little known ) or ( semi-important new physics ) .
 One would think that StackExchange.physics would be the place to determine which . Users could upvote a solid proof, or point out my error, or quote some book that proved it already .

 But mostly I get "Noether's theorem is wonderful" . While true, that does not settle the issue at hand .

Answer (score 0):

Building on the debate on this subject, using classical mechanics, given FULL Conservation of Angular Momentum around all origin points, I can now offer a direct derivation of Conservation of Linear Momentum for N particles .

For N particles in a finite space for which Angular Momentum is fully conserved,
label the particles P1 .. PN
choose an arbitrary origin point P0
choose an instant in time
label the total force on each P1..PN as $\overrightarrow{f1}..\overrightarrow{fN}$
label vector from-P0-to-P1 as $\overrightarrow{r1}$
label each vector from P(n-1) to P(n) as $\overrightarrow{rn}$
AM is conserved around P0
AM is conserved around P1
(torque around P0) $= 0$ :
$0 = ((\overrightarrow{r1}) \times \overrightarrow{f1}) + ((\overrightarrow{r1} + \overrightarrow{r2}) \times \overrightarrow{f2}) + ... + ((\overrightarrow{r1} + ... + \overrightarrow{rN}) \times \overrightarrow{fN})$
(torque around P1) $= 0$ :
$0 = ((\overrightarrow{r2}) \times \overrightarrow{f2}) + ((\overrightarrow{r2} + \overrightarrow{r3}) \times \overrightarrow{f3}) + ... + ((\overrightarrow{r2} + ... + \overrightarrow{rN}) \times \overrightarrow{fN})$
(torque around P0) equals (torque around P1) :
$((\overrightarrow{r1}) \times \overrightarrow{f1}) + ... + ((\overrightarrow{r1} + ... + \overrightarrow{rN}) \times \overrightarrow{fN})$
$= ((\overrightarrow{r2}) \times \overrightarrow{f2}) + ... + ((\overrightarrow{r2} + ... + \overrightarrow{rN}) \times \overrightarrow{fN}$)
( cross product is distributive, pull out all $\overrightarrow{r1}$ terms )
$(\overrightarrow{r1} \times \overrightarrow{f1}) + ... + (\overrightarrow{r1} \times \overrightarrow{fN})$
$+ ((\overrightarrow{r2}) \times \overrightarrow{f2}) + ... + ((\overrightarrow{r2} + ... + \overrightarrow{rN}) \times \overrightarrow{fN})$
$= ((\overrightarrow{r2}) \times \overrightarrow{f2}) + ... + ((\overrightarrow{r2} + ... + \overrightarrow{rN}) \times \overrightarrow{fN})$
( cancel $\overrightarrow{r2}...\overrightarrow{rN}$ terms )
$(\overrightarrow{r1} \times \overrightarrow{f1}) + ... + (\overrightarrow{r1} \times \overrightarrow{fN})  =  0$
( group terms )
$\overrightarrow{r1} \times ( \overrightarrow{f1} + ... + \overrightarrow{fN} )  =  0$
We can choose any arbitrary P0, and therefore choose any $\overrightarrow{r1}$ .
The only way the previous equation is true for all values of $\overrightarrow{r1}$ is :
$\overrightarrow{f1} + ... + \overrightarrow{fN} = 0$
therefore Linear Momentum is conserved

--

The N=2 version is very understandable :
torque around P0 $= 0 = ((\overrightarrow{r1}) \times \overrightarrow{f1}) + ((\overrightarrow{r1} + \overrightarrow{r2}) \times \overrightarrow{f2})$
torque around P1 $= 0 = \overrightarrow{r2} \times \overrightarrow{f2}$
(torque around P0) equals (torque around P1)
$((\overrightarrow{r1}) \times \overrightarrow{f1}) + ((\overrightarrow{r1} + \overrightarrow{r2}) \times \overrightarrow{f2})  =  (\overrightarrow{r2}) \times \overrightarrow{f2}$
( cross product is distributive, pull out all $\overrightarrow{r1}$ terms )
$(\overrightarrow{r1} \times \overrightarrow{f1}) + (\overrightarrow{r1} \times \overrightarrow{f2}) + (\overrightarrow{r2} \times \overrightarrow{f2})  =  \overrightarrow{r2} \times \overrightarrow{f2}$
( cancel $\overrightarrow{r2}$ terms )
$(\overrightarrow{r1} \times \overrightarrow{f1}) + (\overrightarrow{r1} \times \overrightarrow{f2})  =  0$
( group terms )
$\overrightarrow{r1} \times (\overrightarrow{f1} + \overrightarrow{f2})  =  0$
We can choose any arbitrary P0, and therefore choose any $\overrightarrow{r1}$ .
The only way the previous equation is true for all values of $\overrightarrow{r1}$ is :
$\overrightarrow{f1} + \overrightarrow{f2} = 0$
therefore Linear Momentum is conserved

--

So, unless someone can point out an error in my logic, I think this is the answer .

FULL Conservation of Angular Momentum on N Particles proves and enforces Conservation of Linear Momentum .

( Conservation of Linear Momentum does not enforce Conservation of Angular Momentum )

( These proofs do not work for systems that conserve AM only around a single point )

Comment: @JohnRennie This is why I think FULL conservation of Angular Momentum is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can not estimate linear momentum from the angular momentum, no matter how far you put origin.

If you put your origin at z=1 million meters, you can estimate only x and y component of linear momentum from the angular momentum calculated around these origin.

Similarly, for the particles colliding in z-direction, the conservation of angular momentum is trivially satisfied because the origin is located in the same line of the collision. and just because the angular momentum is conserved here, it can not be said that linear momentum is also conserved.

Comment: Given the equation $\vec{L}(\vec{r_2})-\vec{L}(\vec{r_1})=(\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2})\times\vec{p_{total}}$ , ( using units $kg m^2/s^2$ ), if, at some time t : $\vec{L}(0,0,0)=(10,20,30)$ , and  $\vec{L}(1,0,0)=(10,23,28)$ , and  $\vec{L}(0,0,0)=(7,20,31)$ , then we calculate $\vec{p_{total}}=(1,2,3) kgm/s^2$ . So yes, we can calculate LM from AM, no other details needed. And you do not need to be far away , either. But to get three components of LM, you need AM at three non-linear points.

Comment: $kgm^2/s$ and $kgm/s$ , not $s^2$