# Equation of Motion of Rigid Body Represented by Twist and Derivative of Twist

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, acceleration

This question is an extension of question [Understanding terms Twist and Wrench](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298125/understanding-terms-twist-and-wrench).

Assuming there is a rigid body with body twist denoted as $\mathcal{V}_{b}=\left(\boldsymbol \omega_{b}, \boldsymbol v_{b}\right)$.

In eq.8.40 of "Modern Robotics" by K. Lynch, the author presents the 6×6 equations of motion of this rigid body based on wrench and twist:

$\begin{aligned} \mathcal{F}_{b} & =\mathcal{G}_{b} \dot{\mathcal{V}}_{b}-\operatorname{ad}_{\mathcal{V}_{b}}^{\mathrm{T}}\left(\mathcal{P}_{b}\right) \\ & =\mathcal{G}_{b} \dot{\mathcal{V}}_{b}-\left[\operatorname{ad}_{\mathcal{V}_{b}}\right]^{\mathrm{T}} \mathcal{G}_{b} \mathcal{V}_{b}\end{aligned}$

where $\mathcal V_b$ denotes the body twist of this rigid body, and $\mathcal G_b$ is the spatial inertia matrix defined as
$\mathcal{G}_{b}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\mathcal{I}_{b} & 0 \\ 0 & \mathfrak{m} I\end{array}\right]$

In many literature within the field of robotics, including the previously mentioned question, we already know that the derivative of the body twist is

$\dot {\mathcal{V}}_{b}=\left(\begin{array}{c}  \boldsymbol{\alpha}_{b}\\ \mathbf{a}_{b}-\boldsymbol{\omega}_{b} \times \boldsymbol{v}_{A}\end{array}\right)$

where $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{b}$ represents the angular acceleration of the rigid body, $\mathbf{a}_{b}$ represents the ***traditional acceleration***, and the term $\mathbf{a}_{b}-\boldsymbol{\omega}_{b} \times \boldsymbol{v}_{A}$ is called ***the spatial acceleration***.

This dual part of the derivative of the body twist has the physical meaning of the acceleration of the rigid body **without its centripetal acceleration component.**

Now, I am really confused about:

Since the derivative of the body twist has already lost the content of centrifugal acceleration, does this make the 6×6 equations of motion above **incomplete**?

In other words, what I would like to determine in the equations of motion is **the specific form of the dual part of** $\mathcal {\dot V}_b$. Is it the traditional acceleration $\mathbf a_b$or spatial acceleration$\mathbf{a}_{b}-\boldsymbol{\omega}_{b} \times \boldsymbol{v}_{A}$???