# What is the direction of angular momentum? Are Torque and angular momentum same?

Tags: angular-momentum, torque

I just started learning in my class 11 physics book, where I find **Torque** and **angular momentum.** After reading the definition, I am confused about are *Torque* and *angular momentum* are same? If not what is the difference between them? Lastly what is the **direction** of *angular momentum?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, torque and angular momentum are different physical quantities. They don't even share the same units.

The instantaneous angular momentum $\vec {\bf{L}}$ of a particle relative to an axis through the origin is defined by the cross product of the particles instantaneous position vector $\vec{\bf{r}}$ and its instantaneous linear momentum $\vec{\bf{p}}$: $$\vec {\bf{L}} = \vec{\bf{r}} \times \vec{\bf{p}}$$
The net external torque about the same fixed axis in an inertial frame is then $$\sum \vec{\bf{\tau}} = \frac{d\vec {\bf{L}}}{dt}$$

The direction of the angular momentum vector is the direction of $\vec{\bf{r}} \times \vec{\bf{p}}$, which can be found from the [right hand rule.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)

[image]

Hope this helps.

---

[Image source](https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/the-direction-of-angular-momentum-vector-is-class-11-physics-cbse-604ae740ffaa3641accd3648)

Comment: FYI use `\times` for the cross product in math instead of an **x**

Comment: @JohnAlexiou, Fixed, thanks.

Comment: How do you describe motion in that direction? (like "zonal/axial/azimuthal" motion)

Answer (score 0):

As we are aware about the force. It's same with the torque, unofficially we can call it as a *Rotational Force* for better understanding. Which is equal to

$τ = I × α $

Where I is moment of inertia and α is angular acceleration.

let's take an example if you will try to rotate the spring vertically about it's axis let's say clockwise about it's axis you will feel that something is trying to rotate your hand anticlockwise that's the torque, Which is trying to rotate your hand anticlockwisely.

And angular momentum is noting but just a product of it's moment of inertia and the angular velocity.

Let's take an example to understand what's this thing, so when you turn off the rotating fan why does it still rotates even if the motor is turned off. That's because of the angular momentum. It stops slowly because of the heat losses due to friction ,air resistance etc.

So we can say that the angular momentum is something the keeps the object in the circular motion.

Post edit:- the direction of the angular momentum will be same as the direction of angular velocity.

Comment: I never found the linear vs rotational analogies helpful in explaining anything, but rather just as a shortcut to remember the equations. And $L=I \omega$ is not the definition of angular momentum. It just happens to equal this in the narrow case of a rotating rigid body. But in fact, angular momentum can be defined in many other settings, including that of traveling point mass (or orbiting planet). Angular momentum _is the moment of momentum_, $L = r \times p$ by definition.

Comment: @john Yes you are correct but sorry I haven't told anywhere that it's the definition of the momentum i've just discussed the formulation in simple way because that's what I think the simplest way to express the equation.

Comment: And please note that I've used the word "unofficially" that means it's my way of understanding. It's very basic man, when it was taught to me when I was in my 11th grade my professor explained me in the same way. And they are very correct.

Answer (score 0):

*I am going to try to answer plainly and avoid using vector algebra and concepts like the cross product.*

I assume you are familiar with the concept of *torque* as a force at a distance.  If not, [read about torque as the moment of force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/403757/392) with the example of balancing a see-saw. The main takeaway here is that the *perpendicular* distance to the line of action of the force is what is important for torque.

Angular momentum is similarly defined as momentum at distance (moment of momentum, vs. moment of force). Angular momentum tells us that something carrying momentum is at some distance away. Similarly, the *perpendicular* distance to the line of action of momentum (called the percussion axis) is what is important for angular momentum.

Just as you can combine two offset forces that cancel each other out, except still produce a *pure torque* (what is called a force couple), you can combine two moving masses that their momentum cancels out, to produce *pure angular momentum*.

[image: fig1]

$$ L =\left( \tfrac{d}{2} m v \right) + \left( \tfrac{d}{2} m v \right) + d\,(m+m)\,\omega \tfrac{d}{2} = m d^2 \omega $$

Just as the concept of conservation of linear momentum is important, the concept of conservation of angular momentum is important also. Since angular momentum is momentum at a distance, if angular momentum is conserved it means the *perpendicular distance* is conserved as well as the magnitude of momentum.